# Index was outside the bounds of the array not reproducible

Tags: c#, .net, exception, lambda

I get this error on the live product, and I see that it occurs on the last line during list SelectMany, but I could not reproduce it at all. I have tried with different scenarios but in vain.
Any idea on why the exception occurs?

Stack Trace:

> at System.Collections.Generic.List'1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.d_17'2.MoveNext()
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.d_64'1.MoveNext()
> at System.Collections.Generic.List'1..ctor(IEnumerable'1 collection)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable'1 source)

My code:

```
public List<int> GetCategories(SelectQuery query, List<Product> products)
            {
                var filteredQuery = query.FilterItems.Where(f => f.Type != Type.Category);
                var filteredproducts = products
                .Where(x => x.Data != null &&
                x.Data.Category.Any() && filteredQuery.ApplyFilter(x)).ToList();
                return filteredproducts.SelectMany(x => x.Data.Category).Distinct().ToList();
             }
```

Comment: If you couldn't then how do you expect us to? At a guess considering it's `List` code involved at the top of the trace, probably multithreaded access to a list

Comment: show us the exception message or inner exception message

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you very much for your response. I believe so too. The Category which is in the SelectMany Data.Category is a public List<int> GameCategory which has been accessed/modified/read in different places. Do you think this might be the issue? If so, what solution do you recommend? Thank you again

Comment: Doesn't matter how many places, depends how many different threads. If it is multi-threaded, you need `ConcurrentBag`

Comment: @Charlieface OK I will look into it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After you used Where include a .First() or .FirstOrDefault() as the where clause is returning null so it falls over on the next part.

Comment: you could even add a if(filteredQuery!= null) {do something}

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. But I need all the elements, not just the FirstOrDefault and I have already tried making most of the elements in my code to null, but I never get Index out of bound, just null reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `x => x.Data.Category != null` in `Where` before `SelectMany.`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Yes, I will do that, but I think even with out the null check, it should give me a null reference rather than index out of bound. Correct me If I am wrong.Thank you again